# How do I unmount a drive with a script?

Tags: bash, sleep-wake, script

I installed sleepwatcher to run `~/.sleep` before my computer goes to sleep.

I need to unmount `/Volumes/Backup` before my computer falls asleep. If I forget to do it, I get a message telling me that I unsafely unmounted the drive, etc. when the computer resumes. It's a rare external Seagate drive glitch. Lucky me.

So I am trying to remedy the problem with Sleepwatcher by unmounting the drive before the system sleeps. Obviously `sudo` and the password it requires is standing in my way.

Any ideas?

I can't use the `echo "password" | sudo -S xx xx` method because my password contains a dollar ($) sign,  So I need another form of injection.

If I remove the password requirement from `/etc/sudoers`, the system becomes very insecure.

So any creative ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `sudo` to unmount a drive.

## Use `diskutil`

The following command ejects the volume `Backup`:

```
diskutil eject /Volumes/Backup
```

This should do it, although (IIRC) you might want…

```
diskutil unmount /Volumes/Backup
```

…to make it easier to re-mount without having to physically disconnect/reconnect the drive.

### Ejecting All Disks

If you want to make sure you have ejected all of your disks, you can try this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)'
```

### Third Party Tool: Mountain

There is also [Mountain](http://appgineers.de/mountain/) which will automate this for you.

### Third Party Tool: Keyboard Maestro

Above all other ideas, I would recommend [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) which can do all of these things on sleep, and remount your drive on wake, plus 1,000 other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a "$" in your echo statement, you just have to escape it.

```
$ echo "$abc123"
                         <-----Results in a blank line
```

However

```
$ echo "\$abc123"
$abc123                  <-----Works
```

Also, instead of using double quotes, use single quotes to encapsulate your string:

```
$echo '$abc123'
$abc123                  <-----Works
```

Basically, what's happening is that within [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes) ("), it preserves the literal values of the characters with the exception of the dollar sign ("$"), the tilde ("~"), and the back slash ("\").    When you enclose your text within a [single quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes) ('), it preserves all characters, period.

#### Modify Your `sudoers` file.

With that cleared up, **don't save/use passwords in clear text in your script as it's equally insecure!**

Instead, what you should do is modify your `sudoers` file so that you grant "no password" access to that command only.

```
username ALL = (ALL) ALL
username ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/foo/bar/command
```

With this method, you leave your system security intact and allow for the use of `sudo` with no password for this one particular command.